# dispatch called inside useImperativeHandle doesn't call action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-query

I have a component with a save button

```
<Button onClick={() => requestSaveAsync()}>Save</Button>
```

I also need to be able to call requestSaveAsync from the top level of the app, so I added a useImperativeHandle hook inside a custom hook called useEditRow

```
interface Props {
    ref: MutableRefObject<{
        addItem: () => void
    }>
}

const useEditRow = (props: Props) => {
    useImperativeHandle(props.ref, () => ({
        addItem: () => requestSaveAsync()
    })
}
```

The useEditRow hook is inside of an OrderItemTable component

```
const OrderItemTable = forwardRef(function OrderItemTable(props: Props, ref: MutableRefObject<any>) {
    const editRow = useEditRow({
        ref: ref
    })
})
```

The requestSaveAsync method uses useMutation from react-query

```
useMutation(mutateFn, {
  onSuccess: () => dispatch({type: 'clear', name: 'row'})
})
```

Clear row sets the state to initial state. If requestSaveAsync is called by clicking the button, the row is cleared. If I call it through the parent component, the onSuccess function is called, but the dispatch doesn't do anything. If I put a breakpoint on the dispatch function, I see the following code about to called from react_devtools_backend.js

```
  useReducer: function (a, b, e) {
    a = F();
    b = null !== a ? a.memoizedState : void 0 !== e ? e(b) : b;
    z.push({
      primitive: "Reducer",
      stackError: Error(),
      value: b
    });

    // devtools show the empty function on this line will be executed next
    return [b, function () {}];
  },
```

At first I thought that maybe useImperativeHandle was using stale state, so I tried returning {...initialState} instead of initialState. This didn't seem to help. I tried adding the dependencies array suggested by react-hooks/exhaustive-dep. That didn't help. Does anyone know why when dispatch is called from useImperativeHandle, the state doesn't update?

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-glade-fg11v?file=/src/App.js) with some of the basic ideas that were shown abo.

Answer (score 1):

Your `useImperativeHandle` hook doesn't appear to be using the ***forwarded*** React ref. In other words, React refs ***are not*** regular React props that can be accessed by children components.

You should use `React.forwardRef` to correctly forward any passed refs on to the function component.

[React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)
[Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

You didn't include your function component but if you follow the examples in the links provided it's fairly trivial to figure out.

Example:

```
const MyComponentWithSaveButton = (props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    addItem: requestSaveAsync,
  }));

  const requestSaveAsync = () => { .... };

  ...
};

export default React.forwardRef(MyComponentWithSaveButton);
```

Notice here the function component signature not accepts two arguments, the `props` object *and* the React `ref` that is being forwarded, and that the `useImperativeHandle` hook references the forwarded `ref`.

Comment: I've updated my question to show that the ref used in useImperativeHandle comes from the props of a custom hook, which in turn comes from React.forwardRef. Should I use React.forwardRef directly on the hook or does React.forwardRef only need to be used on components?

Comment: @user2453676 `forwardRef` is only used on function components. It's a bit unclear your use case, but is it something like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-snowflake-izj4z?file=/src/App.js)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my use case. Thank you. It was a bit hard for me to simplify the concepts in some of the gigantic components I have, but you have done it very well.

Comment: @user2453676 Regarding `dispatch`, can you share how `requestSaveAsync` callback uses `useMutation`? This seems like an invalid use of a React hook. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).